# Using webpilot API + GPT 4 or GPT 3.5 API

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-3, chat-gpt-4, chatgpt-plugin

Has anyone tried to use the webpilot api with gpt 4 or gpt 3.5 api to be able to have prompts like “Create references for this topic or concept”?

Or basically have access to the internet through GPT4 or GPT3.5 with the help of webpilot?

When I provide this prompt to ChatGPT api without WebPilot, it generates references that don't actually exist, no matter how well I refine the prompt.